# How to check alphanumeric comma separated value using regular expression?

Tags: regex

I need help to write a regular expression for the following strings:

1. Ranges entered must be separated by a comma + space
2. Can take alphanumeric character.
3. Accept - in between but cannot end with - or ,

Following are valid strings:

1. `ABC001, 11236, IU765, OI001-OI007, PO98, 98700`
2. `VA009, VA778`
3. `YU987`
4. `889022`

Following are invalid strings:

1. `,,,&*(&`
2. `AB998,,,,     AB998`
3. `AB005-AB002,-`

Comment: **1** How is valid string #2 valid according to rule #1? **2** Which language/regex engine are you using? **3** Rule #2 is going to be *really* tricky with just regex, can you not check that one programmatically *after* parsing?

Comment: I have changed the Question now.

Comment: I would split the string by `, ` and then check that all the bits are valid alphanumerics

Comment: @Priscy Still though; how is valid string #2 valid according to rule #1? There's no space after the comma.

Comment: And how is #1 valid?? There is a `-` which is not an alphanumeric character

Comment: Sorry. I Changed the Question again.

Comment: what is wrong with invalid example #3

Comment: @Captain the validation should return false if ends with , or -

Comment: I have changed Rule 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following regex

```
^[A-Z0-9]+((,\s|-)[A-Z0-9]+)*[A-Z0-9]+$
```

This checks the following:

- Starts with Alphabets or Numeric
- Checks for `,` or `-` more than 1 pattern
- Ends with Alphabets or Numeric

You can try it online at [Regexr.com](http://regexr.com/)

Answer (score 2):

A regex to follow your rules is `^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:, [a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$`

The rule means:

- From the start `^`
- one-or-more valid characters (though doesn't end in dash) `[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+`
- followed by any number of

  - comma-space
  - followed by one-or-more valid characters
  - --> `(?:, [a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*`
- and then the end `$`

**EDITED** for rules alphanum or dash
**EDITED AGAIN** when the rules changed, again

Comment: Please check the Question again. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @Priscy - please try to work out what you want to ask before you ask it... Downvoting answers because the rules have changed seems a little rude to me

Answer (score 0):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+( *, *[a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

Allows you to have many spaces before and after `,`